# Converting Time/DataTime/Data into java.util.Calendar?

Tags: java, ruby, calendar, timezone, jruby

Is it possible in easy way to convert JRuby Time/DataTime/Data into java.util.Calendar including the timezone?

On #jruby I was given such code `cal.set_time_in_millis(time.to_i)` but I lost information about timezone in betwean. So the more specific question is how to convert the timezone but I prefered to ask more broad questin in case there is simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the #to_java method to convert a Ruby time object to a java.util.Date:

```
require 'java'
Time.now.to_java
```

Note this coersion happens automatically when passing Ruby objects to Java methods.

Comment: IIRC I've posted a bug about it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I get known that the Time does not store timezone so what is returned by `Time.now.zone` is local timezone.

Therefore it is simple to convert to `java.util.Data`:

```
data = java.util.Date.new(date.to_i*1000)
```

Comment: Note that you will lose some precision that way.  This would be more precise: `data = java.util.Date.new(date.to_i * 1000 + date.usec / 1000)`